# How to do a nested if and ISBLANK formula and display the text if it is not blank

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula, formula, equation, excel-2016

I am trying to work out how to do a nested `IF` and `ISBLANK` formula to display the text if it is not blank.

So far I have this:

```
=If(Not(ISBLANK(SCB!A8)),”X”,If(Not(ISBLANK(Voda!A8),”Y”,If(Not(ISBLANK(Fixnetix!A8),”A”,If(Not(ISBLANK(IOW!A8),”B”,”No open cases")
```

It didn't work though and I am trying to pull data from 4 other workbooks that will constantly be changing.

My theory is:

- If X has data, then display but if X does not have data move to Y
- If Y has data, then display but if Y does not have data move to A
- If A has data, then display but if A does not have data move to B
- If B has data, then display but if B does not have data, then display “No open cases”

These are the variables I have

- (SCB!A8)
- (Voda!A8)
- (Fixnetix!A8)
- (IOW!A8)
- "No open cases"

Answer (score 0):

There are a few syntax issues in your attempt.

Here is what I believe will fix it:

```
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(SCB!A8)),”X”,IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Voda!A8)),"A",IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Fixnetix!A8)),"Y",IF(NOT(ISBLANK(IOW!A8)),"B","No OpenCases"))))
```

Basically you were missing several parentheses and also a closing quote. In particular, Several of your internal `NOT(ISBLANK())` combinations were missing the second closing quote.

Answer (score 0):

At some point, using normal formulae for these complex operations becomes counter-productive and fraught with error, as the length of the formula increases.

Once a certain level of complexity is reached, I tend to switch to user-defined functions so that I can simplify the formula and encapsulate the complexity in a single place.

The following function will do what you need:

```
Function FirstMatch(DefaultVal As String, ParamArray Params() As Variant) As String
    Application.Volatile (True)
    Dim i As Integer
    FirstMatch = DefaultVal
    For i = LBound(Params) To UBound(Params) Step 2
        If Range(Params(i)).Value <> "" Then
            FirstMatch = Params(i + 1)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Once you've put that function into your worksheet, the formula to call it becomes a much simpler:

```
=FirstMatch("No open cases", "SCB!A8", "X", "Voda!A8", "Y", "Fixnetix!A8", "A", "IOW!A8", "B")
```

It works simply by setting the return value to the default one, then processing each pair of strings in turn. If the first of the pair is not blank, it will set the return value to the second and return. Otherwise it will keep going until it finds a match or it runs out of possibilities.

If it *does* run out of possibilities, the default return value is returned.

---

Keep in mind there are numerous possibilities to improve that code, such as making the blank detection a little more intelligent (allowing for any white space instead of requiring a completely empty cell) or raising some sort of explicit fault if the argument count is wrong (a hanging cell without a corresponding value to use), but the code shown should be a good start.